# Copy EntityCollection to Dictionary in CRM

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013, adxstudio-portals

I want to convert or copy my EntityCollection to Dictionary.
my code is below.
Please suggest on the same.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
EntityCollection contentCollection = orgService.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(contentQuery));

if (contentCollection != null && contentCollection.Entities != null && contentCollection.Entities.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (Entity contents in contentCollection.Entities)
    {
        dictionary.Add(content.Attributes(0).key,content.Attributes(0).value );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it you want to do. For starters i Think the (0) should be [0], but that would only copy the first attribute of each entity object, which might not even be the same attribute between the objects.

Answer (score 1):

It can be as short as this:

```
EntityCollection contentCollection = orgService.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(contentQuery));
Dictionary<Guid, Entity> dictionary = contentCollection.Entities.ToDictionary(entity => entity.Id);
```

You do not need to check `contentCollection` nor its `Entities` collection, because method `RetrieveMultiple` always returns non-null values or fails throwing an exception.

Alternatively you could write it as one statement:

```
var dictionary = orgService
    .RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(contentQuery))
    .Entities
    .ToDictionary(entity => entity.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an open source project could make this slightly more concise:

```
var dictionary = orgService
    .GetEntities<Entity>(new FetchExpression(contentQuery)
    .ToDictionary(e => e.Id);
```

You can download it from GitHub: https://github.com/daryllabar/XrmUnitTest (Reference the DLaB.Xrm library)
or NuGet: `Install-Package DLaB.Xrm -Version 1.0.1`

The Get Entities Handles the Retrieve and returns a List (for late bound) or List(or whatever type you are retrieving for early bound)